# Grouped boxplot for each column in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, statistics, boxplot

I have a dataset like this:

```
  Y       Gene1       Gene2       Gene3       Gene4     Gene...
TypeI   4.3621833   7.533461    3.9561242   4.457170     ...
TypeII  1.9844923   7.455194    5.4276231   5.440957     ...
TypeIII 1.7273229   8.079968    2.2273002   5.543480     ...
 ...
```

where Y can take on those three values (with 150ish rows).

Now, I'm trying to create a grouped boxplot for every gene (I would have every gene in the x axis and three boxplots for each).

I almost got it to work, but boxplots appear on top of each other, [like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K6GW.png). I've tried playing around with `position_dodge()` and `position_dodge2()` in `geom_boxplot()` but neither works (they have literally 0 effect).

So far, I've tried the following:

```
data %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        cols = -Y,
        names_to = "Genes",
        values_to = "Value"
    ) %>% 
    ggplot(
        aes(
            x = Genes,
            y = Value,
            fill = Y
        )
    ) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(
        title = "test"
    )
```

And the `gather` equivalent:

```
data %>%   
    gather("Genes", "Valor", -Y) %>%    
    ggplot(
        aes(
            x = Genes,
            y = Valor,
            fill = Y
        )
    ) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs(
        title = "test"
    ) -> plot

plot <- ggplotly(plot, width = 2000, height = 1000)
saveWidget(plot, file = "boxplots.html")
```

I also tried to do it with `melt` following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57108482/17157402) but couldn't get it to work.

What can I do to plot the boxplots side by side?

EDIT:

So after some testing I realized that the code for ggplot works fine. I ommited some code because I though the problem was in the boxplot, but it's not.

I added the part that I ommited, but I'll put it here too:

```
data %>% 
(....) -> plot

plot <- ggplotly(plot, width = 2000, height = 1000)
saveWidget(plot, file = "boxplots.html")
```

So the boxplots weren't overlapping in ggplot, but in plotly. Adding `%>%layout(boxmode = "group")` after ggplotly() fixes it. (i.e. `plot <- ggplotly(plot, width = 2000, height = 1000) %>% layout(boxmode = "group")`

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid your issue is not reproducible for others, when generating some random data with `data <- matrix(rnorm(3*4*100, mean = 10 + 1:50*.1), ncol = 4, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("Gene", 1:4))) %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(Y = rep(c("TypeI", "TypeII", "TypeIII"), n()/3))` , your `pivot_longer` and `ggplot` work as expected  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfsfC.png . Could you please edit your question and add output of `dput(head(data))` ?

Comment: Your code looks fine. And when I use the "snippet" of data you provided your code also works fine. So interesting that the dodging does not work for you. The only way to get an image like yours was to set `width=0` in position_dodge.

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot. I was so sure that the problem was in the ggplot part that I didn't add some part of the code which uses plotly. The boxplots where overlapping there, not in ggplot. Thanks for the comments, seeing my code was right was the sanity check I neede to find the real issue :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the last edit, the ggplot code is correct. The problem was in this line: `plot <- ggplotly(plot, width = 2000, height = 1000).

Adding `%>%layout(boxmode = "group")` after ggplotly() fixes it. (i.e. `plot <- ggplotly(plot, width = 2000, height = 1000) %>% layout(boxmode = "group")`